# Problemas al conectar Mysql con VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

Estoy tratando de conectar una BD de Mysql con .NET ya descargue el conector de esta pagina
[Link donde descargue el conector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)

y este es el codigo que utlizo en .NET

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class conexion
Private MysqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
Dim MysqlConnString As String = "server=localhost; user id=root; password=abcd1234"
Public MysqlConexion As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(MysqlConnString)
Public Sub Probarconexion()
    Try
        MysqlConexion.Open()
        MsgBox("La conexion fue exitosa")
        MysqlConexion.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("La conexion no fue exitosa")
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Y mirando la consola me sale el sgte error:
Control vehciulos.exe Error: 0 : The host localhost does not support SSL connections

No se que pueda ser.

agradeceria su ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy destacar las **mejores prácticas** que podemos seguir para conectarnos a mysql utilizando ado.net en vb.net:

Debemos evitar definir las cadenas de conexión dentro del código, ya que para cambiarlas vamos a tener que: modificar el código, compilar e instalar la nueva versión de la aplicación. Lo recomendable entonces, es agregar el archivo de configuración de la aplicación  **app.config**. Allí contamos con la sección dedicada al respecto "connectionStrings".

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MySQLConnString" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=tubasededatos;Uid=root;Pwd=abcd1234"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Volviendo a ADO.NET, debemos asegurarnos de liberar todos los recursos de los objetos luego de utilizarlos. Ej:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    //  Este bloque using libera automáticamente los recursos utilizados por "command"
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Usuarios", conn))

    //  Este bloque using cierra y libera automáticamente los recursos utilizados por "reader"
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Entonces, Tu clase conexion quedaria asi:

```
Public NotInheritable Class Conexion

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ObtenerConeccion() As MySqlConnection
        Return New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MySQLConnString").ToString())
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ProbarConexion() As Boolean
        Using conn = ObtenerConexion()
            Try
                conn.Open()
                Return True
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return False
            End Try
        End using
    End Function
End Class
```

Tu método para probar te quedaría mas o menos así:

```
Public Sub Prueba()
    Try
        If (Conexion.ProbarConexion()) Then
            MsgBox("La conexion fue exitosa")
        End If     

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("La conexion no fue exitosa")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Espero que resuelvas, ya que estoy un poco oxidado en vb.net.

Comment: Gracias, hoy probare tu solucion